# Resistor Value for controlling 5V relay

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi, pullup, pulldown

Regarding the post from: https://www.bambusekd.cz/dev/raspberry-control-5V-relay

Hi I create raspberry pi project for fun and I followed this post for controlling my relay. What formula is used to deduced the values for the resistors?

[image]

Comment: which resistors? ... your schematic shows three ... please label the resistors, for example R1, R2, R3, then refer to them by label .... which part number is Q1?

Comment: what's the point of using a transistor? ... the relay module appears to have one already ... probably does not require the transistor, or any of the resistors

Comment: for all of them.In my case, the transistor is used as switch. That is because the rpi unable to turn off the relay once its on. so using the external controlling circuit helps to raise the GPIO pin output voltage. But now I'm not sure how all the resistor values are calculated but it works

Answer (score 1):

Start with the pull up, that must be low enough resistance that the output can provide enough current to send a high signal.

the next resistor is the pull down on the base, that must be low enough that the transistor stays off when it should be off, even when it's hot.  100K is usually plenty low enough, but 10K works here too.

The final resistor is the base resistor that needs to be low enough to provide enough current to turn the transistor on when the base is at 0.7V and to provide current through the pull down.

In switching circuits it's customary to assume a current gain of 10, so, if the pull up passes 500uA, 50uA is needed in the transistor base, and another 70uA to feed the pull-down resistor.

so it's 120uA

The Raspberry Pi outputs promise about 3V for high so 120uA from 2.3V difference means  19K or less will work here...

For some reason they chose 2K instead of just using another 10K resistor.  Perhaps the output needs to accept more than the current from the pull-up resistor.

That would mean more current through the transistor and thus more needed into the base.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get why we need another 70uA at the pull down resistor?

Comment: There's about 700mV* on transistor's base so with that voltage there's 70uA through the base pull down resistor  that's in additon to the 50uA that we want to flow into the base.  (* more likely it's closer to 600mV but we pretend it's 700 to be on the safe side)